# Mysql - No database selected

Tags: mysql

On every page that uses include_once("include/config.php") it just pops this error: No database selected . I can't figure out where is the problem...

I tried other lots of things I found on google, but still no clue what is the problem.

```
 <?
    $lcMysqlServer = "localhost";
    $lcMysqlUser = "root";
    $lcMysqlPassword = "";
    $lcMysqlUserDatabase = "shop";
    $gnDbConn = mysql_connect($lcMysqlServer, $lcMysqlUser, $lcMysqlPassword) or die ("Error while connecting to server! : ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($lcMysqlUserDatabase, $gnDbConn) or die("Error at selecting the database ".$lcMysqlUserDatabase."! : ".mysql_error());
    ?>
```

Comment: @ethrbunny it's defined as `shop`

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*`, go for `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Do you mean that `mysql_select_db()` returns `true`, yet you get that message? And it isn't neither a PHP error message (which would include file and line number) or a text you typed?

Comment: Whoops - I meant `$gnDbConn`. Make sure it's valid before you call `mysql_select_db`.

Comment: If you're just getting started, please, do not even bother with `mysql_query`. It's a dusty, antiquated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP because of how difficult it is to use correctly. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is much easier to use.

Comment: Exactly, I never wrote in code to say "No database selected" in case of error, but is still showing it. The thing is, even if I write false things at server,user or userdb, is just the same thing. It may be a folder error, how I included the files?

Comment: @tadman , for the moment I am finishing a book that may be a bit older and outdated, but i want to fulfill all it's aplications and problems.

Comment: I really think you're wasting your time learning the `mysql_query` way, which is something that should've died off in the 1990s, and are probably picking up poisonously bad habits that will only hold you back. There are [better references](http://www.phptherightway.com/) available than what you're using. It's like you're saying "I want to learn how to drive, but I want to finish this book on riding horses first."

Comment: Use require_once if you are not sure about your include path, require_once will throw an error while include just produces a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the code you've shared should have such effect. The only way I've found to obtain a `No database selected` text is to call `mysql_select_db()` with an empty argument and print `mysql_error()`'s output:

```
mysql_select_db('', $gnDbConn)
    or die(mysql_error());
```

... or remove the `mysql_select_db()` call and issue a database query:

```
mysql_query('select * from foo')
   or die(mysql_error());
```

Anything like your code will add further output:

```
mysql_select_db('invalid-database', $gnDbConn)
    or die('Error while connecting to server! : ' . mysql_error());
```

> Error while connecting to server! : Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'invalid-database'

So the error must be somewhere else. Tips:

- Make sure you have full error reporting
- Use your editor's search in files feature for isolated `mysql_error()` calls
- Look for database calls before `include_once("include/config.php")`
- Make sure you don't use `mysql_select_db()` inside a function